# Product of char values in a cstring?

Tags: c++, char, c-strings

DISCLAIMER: As a self-professed C++ noob, I probably made a silly oversight. Please don't get mad ;)

Anyway, I'm trying to create a function that turns each individual character of an uppercase cstring into an int (a=1,b=2,...), and then multiply the values. Here is my code:

```
int product(char s[]) {
int curProd = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s);++i) {
    if (s[i] = 'A') {
        curProd = curProd * 1;
    }
    if (s[i] = 'B') {
        curProd = curProd * 2;
    }
    if (s[i] = 'C') {
        curProd = curProd * 3;
    }
```

and so on and so forth. I tried to test this with

```
int main() {
char x[] = "HI";
printf("%d",product(x));
return(0);
}
```

When this was run, the output was 0. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: For speed `for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s);++i) {` change to `for (size_t i = 0; s[i];++i) {`

Comment: To save the keyboard `if (s[i] = 'A') {... etc` one line for all those ifs will suffice i.e `curProd = curProd * (1 + s[i] - 'A')`

Comment: Are you sure you got `return curProd` at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `==`, not `=`. You should pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: And make sure they're turned up (`-Wall` or `/Wall`, for example)

Comment: @EdHeal: Not necessarily. Maybe the last letter multiplies by 0. Depends on what the "so on and so forth" does.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just cast your ASCII character to an integer then subtract 64?  That would remove the need for all your if statements.

Comment: Like what my comment suggested?!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that :(